".Required" validation error is not showing up
I am creating a signup page in Vite typescript, In which I'm using react-hook-form for form handling and Yup for validation. I have 5 fields in sign up form username, full name, email , password and file input for avatar now what happening is that I have created all the fields as required with the help of YUP validation but when I don't pass any image file it doesn't throw the error of "Avatar is required" and jumped to second validation which is of invalid type.
Here is the code of validation schema :
  const validFileExtensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "svg", "webp"];

  function isValidFileType(fileName?: string): boolean {
    if (!fileName) return false;
    const extension = fileName.split(".").pop()?.toLowerCase();
    return extension ? validFileExtensions.includes(extension) : false;
  }

  // validation schema with yup
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().required("Email is required").email("Email is invalid"),
    password: Yup.string()
      .required("Password is required")
      .min(8, "Password must be at least 8 characters long"),
    fullname: Yup.string().required("Full name is required"),
    username: Yup.string()
      .required("Username is required")
      .min(4, "At least 4 characters ")
      .matches(/^\S+$/, "No spaces allowed"),
    avatar: Yup.mixed<File>()
      .required("Avatar is required")
      .test(
        "fileType",
        "Only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, SVG, and WEBP files are allowed",
        (value) => {
          if (!value) return true;
          return isValidFileType(value.name);
        }
      )
      .test("fileSize", "File must be less than 100KB", (value) => {
        if (!value) return true;
        return value.size <= MAX_FILE_SIZE;
      }),

    // --- .test("fileType", "Unsupported file format", (value) => {
    //   if (!value || value.length === 0) return false;
    //   const file = value[0];
    //   return ["image/jpeg", "image/png"].includes(file.type);
    // })
    // .test("fileSize", "File must be less than 2MB", (value) => {
    //   if (!value || value.length === 0) return false;
    //   const file = value[0];
    //   return file.size <= 2 * 1024 * 1024;
    // }), ---
  });

Code of passing schema into react hook form with yupResolver
 const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<SignUpFormInputs>({
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
  });

Code of passing error into "uploadFileInput" component
<UploadFileInput
           label="Upload an Avatar"
           id="uploadAvatar"
           name="avatar"
           errors={errors.avatar?.message}
           register={register}
         />

Code of the "uploadFileInput" component
import React from "react";
import { UseFormRegister } from "react-hook-form";
import { RxAvatar } from "react-icons/rx";

interface SignUpFormInputs {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  fullname: string;
  username: string;
  avatar: File;
}

interface UploadFileInputProps {
  id: string;
  label: string;
  name: keyof SignUpFormInputs;
  errors?: string;
  register: UseFormRegister<SignUpFormInputs>;
}

const UploadFileInput: React.FC<UploadFileInputProps> = ({
  id,
  label,
  name,
  register,
  errors,
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <label
        className="text-[17px]  w-[50%] text-center text-gray-400  text-sm bg-gray-100 file:cursor-pointer p-2 cursor-pointer    file:text-white"
        htmlFor={id}
      >
        <span className=" flex items-center gap-2">
          <RxAvatar size={30} />
          {label}
        </span>
        <input id={id} type="file" className="hidden" {...register(name)} />
        {errors && (
          <p className="absolute  ml-[-9px] text-red-500 text-sm mt-3 ">
            {errors}
          </p>
        )}
      </label>
    </>
  );
};

export default UploadFileInput;

Here's the problem

Thanks in advance.

As you can see below, the avatar is an object of type FileList, therefore it's never a falsy value.

What you can do instead, is create a custom test for a required file:
avatar: yup
  .mixed<FileList>()
  .test("required", "photo is required", (value) => value.length > 0),

